# Uploaded an HTML file as the master page and enabled. Received an error and now site is broken

Tags: 2013, master-page

Uploaded an HTML file as the master page and enabled. Received an error and now site is broken

> Sorry, something went wrong An error occurred during translation of
>   your HTML master page.
>   For more information, please navigate to the
>   master page by clicking the preview button in the Master Page Gallery
>   or directly typing its URL. TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: 5046a89d-10aa-3000-22bb-006ba1d1972d
>
> Date and Time: 9/28/2016 12:14:28 PM

Answer (score 0):

Check your Html file all the divs are closed properly, Master page coding is slightly different from Html. Make sure that you don't have master page coding in Html  page

Html page looks likes this

```
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
```